# CSS, display blocks to different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I got main block, for example it it 400px,
in this block i could have a lot of block, and i have 3 situations
i need to display score on 1 line.

1) When i got 100% - it shold be in the corner of green block

2) When it got a small size, Percentages should have "margin-left: 15px " to text, dont know, how to explain

3) And when it is for example 50% it should be after the bar

And the main problem, all text sholud be in this background, after this i will add onClick function that will close and open Teams(this you will see in the demo), so this block with all background will be receizing onClick, so all DIVs in this block with background

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWXaej

```
class Application extends React.Component {

    percentsToPx ( score ) {
        return score *4
    }

    render() {
        const examples = [
            {
                name: 'Example 1',
                score: 100,
                teams: [ { name: 'Example 1' }, { name: 'Example 1' }, { name: 'Example 1' } ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 2',
                score: 55,
                teams: [ { name: 'Example 2' }, { name: 'Example 2' }, { name: 'Example 2' } ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 1',
                score: 4,
                teams: [ { name: 'Example 3' }, { name: 'Example 3' }, { name: 'Example 3' } ]
            }
        ]
        return <div className='project'>
            {examples.map( ( it, index) => {
                const size = this.percentsToPx( it.score)
                return (
                    <div className='projectTab'>
                        <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
                            <div style={{ width: size, background: 'green', display: 'inline-block' }} className='projectBlock'>
                                <div className='projectText'>
                                    <h1 className='projectTextMain'>{it.name}</h1>
                                    <div>
                                        {it.teams.map( ( team, index ) => {
                                            return (
                                                <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }} key={index}>
                                                    <h2 style={{
                                                        color: 'black',
                                                        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                                                        cursor: 'default'
                                                    }}>{team.name}</h2>
                                                </div>
                                            );
                                        } )}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style={{ width: it.score, display: 'inline-block' }}></div>
                        </div>
                        <h2 className='projectTextPercents'>{it.score}%</h2>
                    </div>)
            })}
        </div>;
    }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

What I want to do
[image]
What I have
[image]

and styles

```
.projects {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin-top: 10px;

&-tab {
        border-top: 1px solid grey;
    &:hover {
            background: white;
        }
    &:last-child {
            border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
        }
    }

&-block {
        display: flex;
        align-items: baseline;
    }

&-text {
        display: inline-block;
        minHeight: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -10px;

    &-main {
            color: black;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: default;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }

    &-percents {
            display: inline-block;
            color: grey;
            margin-left: 10px;
            vertical-align: top;
            cursor: default;
        }
    }
}
```

***THANKS FOR YOUR HELP***

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand what you were asking for at all ... but the best advice I have for figuring out CSS is "hit F12" ... or right-click + "inspect".  You can edit the properties of the page as-is until you get what you want, then put that in your original source.

Comment: @theGleep i know that,
i need to display percents like on picture. Edited my answer, may be now you will understand

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach: as I see, you generate elements' width and put it right in the markup. So, you could generate also an attribute (lets say `data-w`) for an element with value based on the element's width. Then you could target those elements via css. In such a case you need to generate on the server-side some small styles as well for the cases when width is not equal to 100%:

```css
div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    min-height: 38px;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div[data-w="full"]:after {  
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    white-space: nowrap;
    right: 5%;
    content: '100%';
}
/* -- Generate the corresponding styles on the server-side and put them right in the markup for every item with width not equal to 100% -- */
div[data-w="average1"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
  right: -45px;
  content: '50%';
}
div[data-w="average2"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
  right: -45px;
  content: '47%';
}
div[data-w="small"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
  right: -115px;
  content: 'example 3 16%';
}
/* -- End of note -- */
```

```html
<div data-w="full" style="width: 300px">example 1</div> 
<div data-w="average1" style="width: 150px">example 2.1</div>
<div data-w="average2" style="width: 140px">example 2.2</div>
<div data-w="small" style="width: 50px"></div>
```